# power BI: % of subcategory withink category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am struggling with getting % of subcategory within category.
heres my formula for subcateg total
SUBCATEG TOTAL = CALCULATE([Total Sales],ALL('Product'[Subcategory]))
i divide total sales by SUBCATEG TOTAL but it does not give correct result.

Thanks for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGVH3.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a sort of side note in Rob Collie's book on DAX... "Totals not adding up [when you use the SUM() function)"?

his solution is to instead of using SUM('Table'[Column]) use SUMX('Table',[column to sum]) to do the totals. Try that and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Categ Total = CALCULATE([Total Sales],ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Category]))

Subcateg % to Categ = [Total Sales]/[Categ Total]
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately does not work

Comment: your file? i am not sure the Category and Subcategory relation, if Subcategory includes Category then try SubCateg Total = CALCULATE([Total Sales],ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[SubCategory]))